# Changing package name android manifest causes problems JNI

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I have been modifying and playing around with this project:

source code : https://bitbucket.org/viet0904163136/gba-android/src

It's a gameboy advance emulator licensed under GPLv2. Every thing works ok until i change the packagename in the android manifest file.

Without the package name changed the app works without a problem. But when the package name is changed the SDLactivity quits with this message:
(i renamed it to com.gba.emu)

```
   09-01 12:23:16.409: I/SDL(884): SDL_Android_Init()
   09-01 12:23:16.409: W/dalvikvm(884): JNI WARNING: received null jclass
   09-01 12:23:16.419: W/dalvikvm(884):in Lorg/libsdl/app/SDLActivity;.nativeInit:()V (GetStaticMethodID)
   09-01 12:23:16.419: I/dalvikvm(884): "SDLThread" prio=5 tid=17 NATIVE
   09-01 12:23:16.419: I/dalvikvm(884):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x4183fc00 self=0x2a2b6f88
   09-01 12:23:16.419: I/dalvikvm(884):   | sysTid=1148 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=707490776
   09-01 12:23:16.479: I/dalvikvm(884):   | state=R schedstat=( 4273431 73605592 10 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=0
   09-01 12:23:16.589: I/dalvikvm(884):   #00  pc 000012fe  /system/lib/libcorkscrew.so (unwind_backtrace_thread+29)
   09-01 12:23:16.700: I/dalvikvm(884):   #01  pc 0005fd92  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmDumpNativeStack(DebugOutputTarget const*, int)+33)
   09-01 12:23:16.700: I/dalvikvm(884):   #02  pc 00053e28  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmDumpThreadEx(DebugOutputTarget const*, Thread*, bool)+395)
   09-01 12:23:16.700: I/dalvikvm(884):   #03  pc 00053e96  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmDumpThread(Thread*, bool)+25)
   09-01 12:23:16.700: I/dalvikvm(884):   #04  pc 000385c0  /system/lib/libdvm.so
   09-01 12:23:16.700: I/dalvikvm(884):   #05  pc 00038896  /system/lib/libdvm.so
   09-01 12:23:16.709: I/dalvikvm(884):   #06  pc 0003985c  /system/lib/libdvm.so
   09-01 12:23:16.709: I/dalvikvm(884):   #07  pc 0003dbe2  /system/lib/libdvm.so
   09-01 12:23:16.709: I/dalvikvm(884):   #08  pc 000f3bfa  /data/app-lib/com.gba.emu-  1/libmain.so (SDL_Android_Init+549)
   09-01 12:23:16.709: I/dalvikvm(884):   #09  pc 000a7770  /data/app-lib/com.gba.emu-1/libmain.so (Java_org_libsdl_app_SDLActivity_nativeInit+3)
   09-01 12:23:16.709: I/dalvikvm(884):   #10  pc 0001dc4c  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmPlatformInvoke+112)
   09-01 12:23:16.739: I/dalvikvm(884):   #11  pc 0004dcaa  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallJNIMethod(unsigned int const*, JValue*, Method const*, Thread*)+393)
   09-01 12:23:16.739: I/dalvikvm(884):   #12  pc 000385e0  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCheckCallJNIMethod(unsigned int const*, JValue*, Method const*, Thread*)+7)
   09-01 12:23:16.739: I/dalvikvm(884):   #13  pc 0004f696  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmResolveNativeMethod(unsigned int const*, JValue*, Method const*, Thread*)+181)
   09-01 12:23:16.739: I/dalvikvm(884):   #14  pc 00027060  /system/lib/libdvm.so
   09-01 12:23:16.739: I/dalvikvm(884):   #15  pc 0002b580  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*, JValue*)+184)
   09-01 12:23:16.739: I/dalvikvm(884):   #16  pc 0005fcbc  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethodV(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, bool, JValue*, std::__va_list)+291)
   09-01 12:23:16.749: I/dalvikvm(884):   #17  pc 0005fce6  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethod(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, JValue*, ...)+19)
   09-01 12:23:16.749: I/dalvikvm(884):   #18  pc 00054a6e  /system/lib/libdvm.so
   09-01 12:23:16.749: I/dalvikvm(884):   #19  pc 0000ca58  /system/lib/libc.so (__thread_entry+72)
   09-01 12:23:16.749: I/dalvikvm(884):   #20  pc 0000cbd4  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_create+208)
   09-01 12:23:16.749: I/dalvikvm(884):   at org.libsdl.app.SDLActivity.nativeInit(Native Method)
   09-01 12:23:16.749: I/dalvikvm(884):   at org.libsdl.app.SDLMain.run(SDLActivity.java:704)
   09-01 12:23:16.759: I/dalvikvm(884):   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
   09-01 12:23:16.759: E/dalvikvm(884): VM aborting
```

There are 2 packages in the src folder ("com.van.gba" and "org.libsdl.app"). Everything in the jni is pointed to org.libsdl.app. The manifest package name is com.van.gba

when i change com.van.gba it breaks.

So i am wondering, what is causing this problem? I can't find a single refrence to the original package name (com.van.gba) in the jni files.

This error can be simulated by changing the package hierarchy and android manifest package name. (both called com.van.gba) It will occur when loading a gba rom.

(note: before compiling the jni add SDL2_image to LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES += zlib png ( like this `LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES += zlib png SDL2_image`) in the android.mk file under the folder "src")

Comment: What version of Android?  The level of detail in the JNI warnings has generally improved over time, so it's possible a newer version of Android would give a more useful message.

Comment: I was using api level 12 now switch it up to 19. And indeed a more descriptive message.I'm going to edit the post and try to figure it out. thanks!

Comment: Looks like `SDL_Android_Init()`, called from `Java_org_libsdl_app_SDLActivity_nativeInit()`, is passing a null `jclass` argument to `GetStaticMethodID`.  Probably a result of failing to find a class, and then passing the result of `FindClass` along without checking for error.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at [SDL_android_main.c](https://bitbucket.org/viet0904163136/gba-android/src/2761b103a1ba2e7400d7de4a7a3d53cd825e5d0b/jni/src/SDL_android_main.c?at=master), you will find, e.g.

```
void Java_org_libsdl_app_SDLActivity_nativeInit(JNIEnv* env, jclass cls, jobject obj)
{
...
}
```

Which defines a native method of class `SDLActivity` in package `org.libsdl.app`. You must rename all such functions in your **.c** files if the package of the `SDLActivity` is renamed.

On the other hand, there is no need to rename the package of the Java class when you rename the APK package. It is also often convenient to create a small "native wrapper" Java class, and move all native methods to this class; then call them from this class. This is especially relevant for static native methods.

**==== Update ====**

Here is another place where the package name is hardwired:

See [class com.van.gba.SelectGameActivity](https://bitbucket.org/viet0904163136/gba-android/src/2761b103a1ba2e7400d7de4a7a3d53cd825e5d0b/src/com/van/gba/SelectGameActivity.java?at=master)

```
    String strTempPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
    strTempPath += "/Android/data/";
    strTempPath += SelectGameActivity.this.getPackageName();
    File dir = new File(strTempPath);
```

It is looking for some files based on its package name; it assumes that its package name is equal to the APK package name. There are probably more places like this in your code. When you have them fixed, you will be able to rename the APK package.

Comment: yes this is true but the code is structured like this. All the native methods are pointing to org.libsdl.app.(SDLActivity) And i did not change this i only changed the package name (com.van.gba) In the manifest and the package hierarchy(com.van.gba). I dind't edit the org.libsdl.app package hierarchy. This was my problem ,no native method is pointed to com.van.gba.But still it breaks because of the android manifest package name change. And i could not figure out what the android manifest package name has to do with the files in JNI. (I could not find a single refrence to com.van.gba in the JNI

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your problem. Please see the updated answer.

Comment: yes that directory is created to store save files and load them. When i changed the manifest apk package name i also renamed/refactored the hierarchy package with the equal name com.van.gba. So i don't think there should be a problem with that because the package name is not hardcoded anywhere else. Thanks for your help and time. I have been searching and trying to find a solution for like 8 hours now :P It's really strange and frustrating. the error accours on calling SDL_Android_Init with the message above. JNI warning : received null jclass..

Comment: If you made some changes that are not reflected in https://bitbucket.org/viet0904163136/gba-android/src/2761b103a1ba?at=master, then it is very hard to find the problem. I must admit that `"received null jclass"` is a strange warning. But you maybe really SDLMain launches the method when SDLActivity class is not ready yet? Put a breakpoint there and try to see what happens there.