# Changing package name android causes problems JNI

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I have been modifying and playing around with this project:

source code : https://github.com/schwabe/ics-openvpn
when I change the package name from de.blintk.openvpn to de.blinkt.vpn i have this eror message :

```
  java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found: de.blinkt.vpn.NativeUtils.getNativeAPI:()Ljava/lang/String;
```

I tried to modify this code `Java_de_blinkt_openvpn_NativeUtils_getIfconfig(JNIEnv* env)` to

```
Java_de_blinkt_vpn_NativeUtils_getIfconfig(JNIEnv* env)
```

but nothing changed the error is still!
I found simller Q in [Changing package name android manifest causes problems JNI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25595634/changing-package-name-android-manifest-causes-problems-jni)
but I coudn't solve my problem, anyone help me please
thank :)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please paste your code in the question itself instead of linking us to it.

Comment: Did you rebuild your native code after changing the method name?